# vb.net Get text from hidden html element

Tags: html, vb.net, htmlelements

I don't have a problem with extracting/parsing parts of HTML, but part of HTML code, that I am interested in (link) is hidden from page source code...

```
 $("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
    $("#ResultSection").hide();
});

$("#loading").ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#ResultSection").show();
});

function hideAllSections() {

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#load").hide();
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

... (it's visible when page is loaded in browser). I've tried to get that link by simulating tab/click in VB.net's `webbrowser` but it doesn't work all the time.

But same part (link) is visible when I select and click on inspect element.

[image]

Is it possible to somehow extract that information from web page?

EDIT 1

Link to webpage : http://pretraga2.apr.gov.rs/ObjedinjenePretrage/Search/Search

Table that contains link in question is created when value : 20084693 is entered in first textbox. After that click on button "Претражи"

Link that I'm after is : http://pretraga2.apr.gov.rs/EnterprisePublicSearch/details/EnterpriseBusinessName/1096795?code=0C3D59BDA4A2DCF4C23721E90BCFFEC4A8B3D4D1 Part of link after code= is changed every few minutes.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? Or provide a live demo of the involved code so we can fiddle around with the code? :) And do provide more details about which link exactly do you wanna get

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: JQuery code you provided, how is it related to your problem?

Comment: Mladene, I am not familiar with javascript, just basic stuff. Part of code in main post is there for additional info on how that page is generated, nothing else,

Answer (score 1):

Create a bookmark in your web-browser.

Put any name you want, then put the following as the URL:

```
javascript:$.post("http://pretraga2.apr.gov.rs/ObjedinjenePretrage/Search/SearchResult", {'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest', 'rdbtnSelectInputType':'mbr', 'SearchByRegistryCodeString':prompt("Code: "), '__RequestVerificationToken': $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()}, function(data){prompt("Link: ", $(data).find("a").attr('href'))});
```

Then go to the search page and click on the the bookmark.

It will ask you for "Code" (the example you gave was 20084693) and click ok. It will give you the link you are looking for **if** a search result was returned.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works in IExplorer. Thank you, but I need that in VB, can you help me with that? Or at least help me understand what did you do, maybe I can apply that to VB.

Comment: The code performs the exact action that happens when you click the search button. It asks you for the code in a pop-up message, then builds up the search query and asks the server to execute it. When the server returns the _table_, it finds the link in it and displays it in another popup. The catch here is that everytime the page is loaded or refreshed, the hidden field value "__RequestVerificationToken" changes. Therefore you need that page open for a valid search

Comment: Actually I need to find a way from the search page to the link, so that I am able to use that link in application without manual copy/paste. The number I provided in original post is one of many, so generated link is going to be different every time. Anyway you helped me with the first step. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you stored the link in a variable at the beginning of the ready function? That way you would have the link stored in the variable and could get it whenever you wanted to.

Comment: But I don't know how to extract that link, it is generated after specific numeric value is inserted in webpage textbox. Link is not in HTML page source (it's hidden), it's only shown in webpage.